# How can I get numeric values instead of Logarthmic values in D3 axis scale?

Tags: svg, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I tried the following code,

```
d3.scale.log().domain([1,4]).range([h, 0]);
```

In the axis I'm getting values as **1e+0, 2e+0, 3e+0, 4e+0** in the axis value. But I need the lograthmic values such as 10, 100, 1000, 10000 ..etc....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `log.scale`'s `tickFormat` in conjunction with the axis `tickFormat` function.

eg. set up 1 -> 10000 log scale:

```
var s = d3.scale.log().domain([1, 10000]).range([1000, 0])
```

then, set up the axis:

```
var axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(s).tickFormat(function (d) {
        return s.tickFormat(4,d3.format(",d"))(d)
})
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/2hvxc/

We want 4 ticks - one for each power of 10 - and formatted with a comma to a digit.

Learn more about formatting here:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting

Learn more about log scales here:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-log

And axis:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickSize